# Search Column for Text, take value in column to the right and move it up 1 row

Tags: excel, vba

I have a rather large data dump I receive and I have to search column E for the word "to". If it comes up, I need the value to the right of the cell (column F) to be moved up 1 row (cut and paste) and then continue searching column E for any other "to"'s.

Here's the code:

```
Sub Format_DFG()

Dim cell As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each cell In Range("E1:E" & Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)
    If InStr(cell.Text, "to") > 0 Then
        cell.Offset(1, 0) = cell.Text
        cell.ClearContents
    End If
Next cell

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

So what's it currently doing is moving the word "to" to the column to the right. I need it to take the value of the cell to the right of the word to and move it up 1 row.

e.g. It finds the word "to" in cell E20. Take the value from F20 and move it up to F19.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary that you show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you ([No attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)). Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what isn't working?

Comment: `cell.Offset(1, 0)` is the cell below, `cell.Offset(0,1)` is cell to right. So you want `cell.Offset(-1, 1) = cell.Offset(0,1))`